# For loop in Go programming language

Tags: go

I am writing a function to reverse a string using Go.

```
func main() {
        s := "abcde"
        r := []rune(s)
        for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i++, j-- {
               r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
        }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(r))
}
```

However, the compiler complaints about `i, j = i++, j--`, says, 
`syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting {`.

This function works if i change that into `i, j = i+1, j-1`.
I don't know why this isn't allowed. Anyone can help?
Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, `x--` and `x++` are statements, not expressions, so you can't assign them like that, and it's by design.

The [Spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operator_precedence) says:

> Unary operators have the highest precedence. As the ++ and -- operators form statements, not expressions, they fall outside the operator hierarchy. As a consequence, statement *p++ is the same as (*p)++.

Comment: Furthermore, in languages where they are expressions, `i = i++` is a bit pointless: "increment `i`, and store the pre-increment value in `i`"?